# Replacing cell values with column header value

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe:

`a-line abstract ... zippered 
   0        0    ...     0
   0        1    ...     0
   0        0    ...     1`

Where the value of the cell is `1` I need to replace it with the header name.

`df.dtypes` returns `Length: 1000, dtype: object`

I have tried `df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(object).replace(1, x.name))`

but get `TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'int'`

other attempts:

`df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(object).replace(str(1), x.name))` == `TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'`

`df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).replace(str(1), x.name))` == `Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'`

Comment: I added a timing comparative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea to all three solutions below is to loop through columns. The first method is with `replace`.

```
for col in df:
    df[col]=df[col].replace(1, df[col].name)
```

Alternatively, per your attempt to `apply` a lambda:

```
for col in df_new:
    df_new[col]=df_new[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('1',df_new[col].name))
```

Finally, this is with `np.where`:

```
for col in df_new:
    df_new[col]=np.where(df_new[col] == 1, df_new[col].name, df_new[col])
```

Output for all three:

```
       a-line   abstract   ...    zippered
0       0       0          ...    0
1       0       abstract   ...    0
2       0       0          ...   zippered
```

Comment: thanks, the np.where one was the only one that worked for some reason

Comment: make sure you are setting back the answer on the left side of the equation: i.e. df[col]=  That usually gets me.

Comment: Also, the reason why your solution wasn't working is because what you are replacing is *dynamic* to the column name, versus a *static* string or something, so 1) you have to do a basic loop as I have done or 2) do something more creative that might be unnecessarily complex

Answer (score 2):

You might consider to play from this idea

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0],
                  [0,1,0],
                  [0,0,1],
                  [0,1,0]],
                  columns=["a","b","c"])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df==1, df.columns, df),
                  columns=df.columns)
```

## UPDATE: Timing

@David Erickson solution it's perfect but you can avoid the loop. In particular if you have many columns.

### Generate data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 1_000
columns = ["{:04d}".format(i) for i in range(n)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=2, size=(4,n)),
                  columns=columns)
# we test against the same dataframe
df_bk = df.copy()
```

### David's solution #1

```py
%%timeit -n10
for col in df:
    df[col]=df[col].replace(1, df[col].name)
```

```
1.01 s ± 35.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### David's solution #2

```py
%%timeit -n10
df = df_bk.copy()
for col in df:
    df[col]=df[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('1',df[col].name))
```

```
890 ms ± 24.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### David's solution #3

```py
%%timeit -n10
for col in df:
    df[col]=np.where(df[col] == 1, df[col].name, df[col])
```

```
886 ms ± 12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

### Avoiding loops

```py
%%timeit -n10
df = df_bk.copy()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df==1, df.columns, df),
                  columns=df.columns)
```

```
455 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```